# How to add text into a specific file line?

Tags: python, file

I have a bunch of files already written and I have to add a text line into them, in the first line. I tried to do that with `seek()`, but this method overrides the text from the first line. I'm looking for something that shifts everything and add the text.

```
def add_line(file):
    with open(file,'r+') as f:
        text="my_text"
        for line in f:
            if text in line:
                break
        else:
            f.write(text)
            print("Text was added in\n"+ file)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to write a temporary file with the line + the old file, for each file. I think it would be an easier task if you do it with a shell script (with cat, for example).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to do it with a shell script, but I'll try your solution with temporary file. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :

```
def add_line(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    text = 'my_text\n'
    lines.insert(0, text)
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(lines))
```

you are reading all the lines, insert your new line at index 0, and then write to your file all the lines + your new line, in this way you can insert a new line at any index you want

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's called file offset, and it don't move automatically if you override the data it points at.

You need to read the file first, then open a new file (here you can override the file) and write the data as you need. Consider this file:

```
→ cat file.text
line1
line2
line3
```

And this code

```
lines = ""
with open('file.text', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()

with open('file.text', 'w') as newf:
    newf.write("new first line\n")
    newf.write(lines)
```

After executing it, the file content would look like:

```
→ cat file.text
new first line
line1
line2
line3
```